# Prevent multiple user active session

Tags: codeigniter

I want to logout the user if the same user logs in to another computer.
In my CI3 I have the following config.

```
$config['sess_driver']             = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']        = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_expiration']         = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path']          = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']           = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']     = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

That would store user session to my database `ci_session`.
However, I want to prevent user to have multiple active session. Let say if user logs in to another computer his existing session should destroy.

Q1. How do I check if user is logged in? In my `ci_session` database, I can only see the blob type in user data column.

Q2. How to destroy his other active session if he logs to another computer?